# Does Binding Order Matter When Using WhenInjectedExactlyInto and a Default Binding?

Tags: ninject

With multiple Ninject modules, I end up having a binding order for a particular interface which looks like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(TroubleshootingLogger), typeof(RegularAndStashLogger), typeof(LogStashLogger), typeof(KafkaSendClient));
Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<TroubleshootingLogger>();
Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<RegularAndStashLogger>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto<ProcessConfiguration>();
```

My question is if, when I call the Kernel for an instance of ProcessConfiguration, will it inject TroubleshootingLogger (the default bind), or RegularAndStashLogger (the exact bind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and built a small test program to determine this myself (I acknowledge I should have done this first).

As it turns out, Ninject does appear to check all "WhenInjectedExactlyInto" bindings before falling back to a default binding.

The program (which depends on Ninject to run, duh): pastebin.com/9Kpsb25h